# HTML or JAVA Script for my random page viewer

Tags: javascript, html

**Hi Everyone**

Please help me on getting html code or javascript. 
I'm really new on to this thing. I just wanted to have a page generator to generate a random page on our company website.

where you will be click a link then it will redirect you on a random page on your website.

our company url pages will be like this.

http://www.company.com/pages/xxxx.pdf

Where if i click on get random page, it will go on 1123.pdf .. pages will be random from 1xxxx to 3xxxx.

i would like to make it simple and should be on one page.

Thanks! :D

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Are you having a very specific problem with this? That's the kind of thing Stack Overflow is for. No one is going to design your application for you and give you a lengthy tutorial/have a long conversation about how to make it.

Comment: none so far. :) got a restriction on our company internet i just wanted to send it on my email and copy paste it on my workstation as html

Comment: It's JavaScript not Java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I've added comments to the code that explain how everything works.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Open random url</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Function to generate random number */
        function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        }

        /* Wait untill the document is fully loaded */
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            /* Catch click event on hyperlink */
            document.getElementById("randomLink").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                /* Prevent the browser from following the hyperlink */
                event.preventDefault();

                /* Generate random number between 1000 and 4000 */
                var randomNumber = randomIntFromInterval(1000, 4000);

                /* Redirect to a random PDF file on the website */
                window.location.href = "http://www.company.com/pages/"+ randomNumber +".pdf";
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="randomLink">Open random PDF</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow Thanks i'll try it later

Comment: @MarkReinhardGatebPascua If an answer has helped you out, make sure to mark it as "Accept answer". It's a way to show your appreciation to the person that helped you out and it prevents the question from remaining unanswered forever.